# Material UI - Google Maps Autocomplete - Restrict to city and state?

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, autocomplete, material-ui, google-places-api

I'm using the Google Maps Places Autocomplete that comes with Material UI and I'm stuck on trying restrict the results. When a user starts typing the only suggestions I want returned are City, State for them to select.

Here is a link to MUI's documentation with example:
[Material UI - Google Places Autocomplete](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#google-maps-place)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the code from the library is using the [AutocompleteService.getPlacePredictions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-autocomplete-service#AutocompletionRequest). To achieve your use case you need to include the `types` properties with value of `['(cities)']` to your AutocompleteService.getPlacePredictions request. This will instructs the Places service to return results that match locality or administrative_area_level_3 as stated [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/supported_types#table3)

You can add it inside the fetch in the code sample just like below:

```
 fetch({ input: inputValue, types: ['(cities)'] }, (results) => {
      if (active) {
        let newOptions = [];

        if (value) {
          newOptions = [value];
        }

        if (results) {
          newOptions = [...newOptions, ...results];
        }

        setOptions(newOptions);
      }
    });
```

Here's the [sample code](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-3psiv?file=/demo.js). Make sure to use your API key for the sample to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
fetch(
  {
    input: inputValue,
    types: [
      "country",
      "administrative_area_level_1",
      "administrative_area_level_2",
      "locality",
    ],
  },
  (results) => {
    if (active) {
      let newOptions = [];

      if (value) {
        newOptions = [value];
      }

      if (results) {
        newOptions = [...newOptions, ...results];
      }

      setOptions(newOptions);
    }
  }
);
```

see the different place types you can use [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/supported_types)